# JSON document was not fully consumed exception is showing when using retrofit and rxjava2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am using retrofit and rxjava2 to save data in database data is added successfully but it is showing exception below:

```
JSON document was not fully consumed
```

Why this exception is showing even if there is no error and my data is added successfully in database.After data added I want to show successful message send by the server but after adding data exception message is showing instead of successful message.

I have tried my api with postman after successful POST request message from server is showing in postman.

Below is my code:

**ApiService.class**

```
public interface ApiService {

@POST("saveData")
@FormUrlEncoded
Single<String> saveDataOnServer(@Field("Name") String Name,
                                @Field("Age") String Age);

}
```

**RetrofitClient.class**

```
public class RetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

private static final String URL = "https://example.com/";

public static Retrofit getInstance(){

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .readTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .writeTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .build();

    if(retrofit == null){

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                       .baseUrl(URL)
                       .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                       .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
                       .client(okHttpClient)
                       .build();
    }

    return retrofit;
  }

private RetrofitClient(){

  }

}
```

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {

@SerializedName("Name")
@Expose
String Name;

@SerializedName("Age")
@Expose
String Age;

public Employee(){

}

public Employee(String Name,String Age){

    this.Name = Name;
    this.Age = Age;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return Age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    Age = age;
}
}
```

**AddEmploy.class**

```
public class AddEmploy extends AppCompatActivity {

ActivityAddEmployBinding activityAddEmployBinding;
Repository repo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_employ);

    activityAddEmployBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_add_employ);

    activityAddEmployBinding.setAddButton(this);

    repo = new Repository(this);

}

public void add(View view){

repo.addEmployee(activityAddEmployBinding.name.getText().toString(),activityAddEmployBinding.age.getText().toString());

   }
 }
```

**Repository.class**

```
public class Repository {

Context context;

public Repository(Context context){

    this.context = context;

}


 public void addEmployee(String str1,String str2){

     Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
     ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

     apiService.saveDataOnServer(str1,str2).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                           .subscribe(addEmployObserver());
 }

 private SingleObserver<String> addEmployObserver(){

     return new SingleObserver<String>() {
         @Override
         public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {


         }

         @Override
         public void onSuccess(String s) {

             Toast.makeText(context,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         @Override
         public void onError(Throwable e) {

             Toast.makeText(context,"Error: "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
     };
   }
}
```

Someone please let me know why this exception is showing.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: How does the JSON document you are receiving look like.

Comment: It look like {  "Name": "John" , "Age":"20"}